# angularjs Dependency Injection not properly importing external npm libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Am newbie to angularjs. Stuck at a very silly point.

I am trying to create a small angular app which should use npm library hidemyass-**scraper**.

Below is my code :

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/google-play-scraper/lib/google-play-scraper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mine.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
</body>
</html>
```

mine.js :

```
 var scraper = angular.module('scraper', []);
 scraper.constant('gps', ['$window', function($window) {
 return $window.google-play-scraper; 
}]);

 angular.module('myapp',['scraper'])
.controller('mycontroller',['$scope','$window','gps', function($scope,$window,gps){
    
//var gplay = require('google-play-scraper'); So now gplay should be availale and i cant use require in angularjs

gplay.app({appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies'})
  .then(function(app){
    console.log('Retrieved application: ' + app.title);
  })
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log('There was an error fetching the application!');
  });
    
}]);
```

ERROR MESSAGE IN CHROME :

```
google-play-scraper.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
angular.js:13424 ReferenceError: gplay is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (mine.js:17)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4625)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10027)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8965)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8333)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8213)
    at angular.js:1715
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17125)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1713)
```

What am i doing wrong here....

Comment: Are you sure the node version of this library has all the code you need in its index.js?

Comment: Yes it was initally , It was pointing to other js in lib folder, Updated my question with actual files. The issue is require function is in external npm library google-play-scraper.js . Which calls other js what has many more requires ... any help is appreciated